# Generating a Population Data Set in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, nested-loops, sas-macro, do-loops

I am very new to SAS and I am trying to generate a population data set of categorical variables.  I need to get a data set with 400 observations and 99 variables.  The first column (Variable 1) will have 4 1's and 396 0's, the second column (Variable 2) will have 8 1's and 392 0's, and so on and so forth until the last column (Variable 99) will have 396 1's and 4 0's.  I have been trying to generate this data set but had no luck so far.  I believe I have to make use of MACROS and DO-LOOPS, ARRAYS and maybe even nested LOOPS.

So far this is what I have but I am pretty I am far from the actual solution;

```
DATA population;
    ARRAY pop V1-V99;
        DO N=1 TO 400;
           DO i=1 TO dim(pop);
               pop(i)=.....;
           END;
        DROP i;
        DROP N;
        END;
RUN;
```

Comment: Arrays create a row of data, not columns. Can you redefine your requirements in terns of rows not columns? If not, I suppose you could generate the data and then transpose it.

Comment: Standard statistical analysis structure require me to maintain my variables as columns, and rows as respondents (or observations). So unfortunately I will not be able to redefine my requirements in terms of rows, also  I did not see a relationship among the rows.  But I am open to trying out your idea of generating the correct transposed version of the data set.  Do you happen to have an idea of how I would go about doing that?

Comment: So for the first variable you want 4 out of 400 observations be true and the rest false.  Do you care which observations get set to true?  Can it be the first 4? The last 4? Or does it need to be 4 random observations?

Comment: It does not matter which 4 observations are true. Any of those 3 scenarios you have listed would work for me

Comment: Simplified my answer slightly, hopefully that's dynamic enough for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure how this will help, but this seems to get you there:

First create the rows/columns values in a long list and then flip to a wide structure as desired. This is dynamic and easily modified for any number of rows/columns or selection of 1s. The 1's are just selected in order, you didn't specify if they needed to be random or sequential.

```
 data have;
 *loop over 99 columns;
 do col=1 to 99;
     *create row values, using 4 rule and basic math for loop counting;
     do row=1 to 400;
         if row <= col*4 then val=1; 
         else val=0;
         output;
     end;
end;
run;

*sort for transpose;
proc sort data=have;
    by row col;
run;

*flip to desired structure;
proc transpose data=have out=want prefix=COL;
by row;
var VAL;
id col;
run;

*check # of 1's per col;
proc means data=want N SUM;
var COL1-COL99;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to want to increment by fours a little arithmetic should do the trick. Just test if the current row is less than the current column number times 4.

```
data population;
  do row=1 to 400;
    id='ID'||put(row,z3.);
    array vars v1-v99 ;
    do col=1 to dim(vars);
      vars[col]= row <= 4*col;
    end;
    output;
  end;
  drop row col;
run;
```

To see if we got the right number of ones we can add them up:

```
proc means sum; run;
```

Results:

```
Variable             Sum
------------------------
v1             4.0000000
v2             8.0000000
v3            12.0000000
v4            16.0000000
v5            20.0000000
v6            24.0000000
v7            28.0000000
v8            32.0000000
v9            36.0000000
v10           40.0000000
v11           44.0000000
...
v96          384.0000000
v97          388.0000000
v98          392.0000000
v99          396.0000000
```

Comment: Nice and succinct, as always!

Answer (score 0):

```
data line;
do i = 1 to 100;
    do j = 1 to 100;
        select; 
            when (i > j) k = 0;
            otherwise k = 1;
        end;
        output;
    end;    
end;
run;

proc transpose data = line
out = cube (drop = _NAME_);
by i;
id j;
var k;
run;

proc sql;
create table quad_cube_prep as
select t1.* from cube t1
union all
select t2.* from cube t2
union all
select t3.* from cube t3
union all
select t4.* from cube t4
;quit;

proc sort data = quad_cube_prep out=quad_cube (drop = i) ; by i;
```

Basically generate a line column of 10000 entries
fold it 100 using transpose to get a cube.
and union all x4 to get the quad repetition.

Comment: Quality stuff, thank you for this alternate approach!